# Despliegue django en diferentes plataformas

Tags: python

hola espero me puedan ayudar... (lo he intentado todo)
he buscado desplegar una api hecha en django en diferentes plataformas pero es imposible aunque las carga y subí todos los archivos sin problemas me termina dando "server error 500"
no se el porque, pero en la única plataforma que puedo ver el error y su equipo de soporte me dice que el problema esta en mi código!
quise desplegar en:
-heroku
-render.com
-railway
-pythonanywhere

en todas y siempre termina dando error. no tengo problemas en compartir el código y que alguien me diga que es lo que estoy haciendo mal y que es lo que esta mal !
gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ese es el tema que en una sola plataforma en el "logs" me dio un error y es lo que dice "GET  / http/1.1" 500 145, luego de esto los navegadores! esto fue en renders.com del resto soporte solo dice "el error esta en su codigo"